# C++ unordered map error

Tags: c++, types, unordered-map

I'm trying to declare an unordered map into my program in which I will map them to tokens in another file.

I need a method which returns the Token type found in Token.h (which is an `enum class`)

What is confusing me is that, since I want to return the mapped Tokens from the `unordered_map` to the `enum class`, what should be the return type of the method? Also, it is stating that

`error: 'unordered_map' does not name a type`

I am rather new to C++ and am still finding it a bit hard in this case how I should declare methods. I've read that the unordered map should be declared INSIDE a method, but since I want the value returned by the map, which should be the return type?

---

I tried this

### Test 1

```
Token Lexer::getTokenType()
{
   unordered_map<string,Token> tokenType;

}
```

This outputs these errors:
[image: Errors]

### Test 2

I tried this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <map>


#include "lexer.h"


using namespace std;

long Row, Col, Offset;

unordered_map<string, Token> ProtectedWords
{

}
```

OR

```
unordered_map<string, Token>::Lexer::getTokenType()
{
}
```

still yielded the same

Its error: [image: Error]

I know these do sound stupid, but would you mind explain to me please? As in the tutorial I followed many are, yes, called inside a method, but even that did not work

---

Comment: #include <unordered_map>

Comment: [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) uses a different header file from [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: Looks like you aren't `#include <unordered_map>` (or boost/unordered_map, or tr1/unordered_map depending on what compiler you're using)

Comment: Which version of compiler do you use and with what flags? Unordered map were standardized in c++11.

Comment: And please, in the future don't post images of text. Copy and paste the text into the question instead. I'm sure that the errors (and complete build log) could be gotten as text.

Comment: yes, I noticed that I included MAP not Unordered map

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to include `<unordered_map>`.

You'll also need to enable C++11 support, if you haven't already done so: for GCC, make sure the compiler arguments include `-std=c++11` (or `c++0x` if you're using an old compiler).

Comment: I noticed I was including the wrong map, and also I am usign C++11. 
Still the result stayed the same. Since I want to return the Token Type, which should be the best way to declare the method?

Comment: @DodoSerebro: `Token Lexer::getTokenType()` should be fine, if it's supposed to return a single token. How you implement it depends on exactly what you're trying to do - you'll need to get a `Token` from somewhere (perhaps a map stored as a member of `Lexer`?) and return it.

Comment: I have a file called Token.cpp and Token.h ... Token.h is an enum class which consists of all the tokens I need for the parser/compiler. Now I will check each character and added to a buffer, and then compared to the list of tokens, and when matched, I will return that particular token